# What's the time complexity of this recursive algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Here is a algorithm question:

> Given a string s and a dictionary of words dict, add spaces in s to
>   construct a sentence where each word is a valid dictionary word.
>
> Return all such possible sentences.
>
> For example, given s = "catsanddog", dict = ["cat", "cats", "and",
>   "sand", "dog"].
>
> A solution is ["cats and dog", "cat sand dog"].

The solution is as following, but I was struggled to determine the time complexity of this solution. Can someone give me some hints, especially if interviewers asked this time complexity in the interviews, is there a quick way to find it without too much math?

```
public class Solution {
    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap();
    public List<String> wordBreak(String s, Set<String> wordDict) {
        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(s == null || s.length() == 0) {
            return res;
        }
        if(map.containsKey(s)) {
            return map.get(s);
        }
        if(wordDict.contains(s)) {
            res.add(s);
        }
        for(int i = 1 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
            String t = s.substring(i);
            if(wordDict.contains(t)) {
                List<String> temp = wordBreak(s.substring(0 , i) , wordDict);
                if(temp.size() != 0) {
                    for(int j = 0 ; j < temp.size() ; j++) {
                        res.add(temp.get(j) + " " + t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        map.put(s , res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can the dictionary contain strings which are not sub-strings of the given string s?

Comment: @PEF Yes, it can.

Answer (score 4):

Time complexity is `O(2^n * n)`.

The number of maximal such word breaks is `2^(n-1)`, with the [bijection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection) to binary vectors of length `n-1`: For each space between two characters, you can either break the word there (1 in the vector) or not (0 in the vector), giving you `2^(n-1)` such possible words.

Since creating each string, calculating its hash and adding it to the set is `O(n)` (the substring's length), you get `O(2^n * n)`.

You get the worst case for:

```
dict = [a, aa, aaa, aaaa, ....]
s = "aaaaaaaaa...a"
```

Your `map` ensures you do not do duplicated work, using [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).  (Without that, complexity would have been factorial of `n`, but using it you avoid duplicate work like recalculating from scratch the prefix of "aaa...a|a|a" and "aa...a|aa"

Comment: And just adding a comment in case someone wonders: O(2^n) and O(2^(n-1)) are the same complexity class.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation. From your analysis, it seems that for this kind of recursive algorithm, the calculation for its time complexity may not come the line-by-line analysis of  code, but more like from the problem itself, is that right?

Comment: @Leo It is a combination of both. The code is analyzed as well to make sure there is no double processing. Since this is the case, by finding the worst example, you can get the complexity